# Comparing adjacent rows in single table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to compare adjacent, descending rows in an mysql table. The data has three columns:

```
 Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
date 1   apple    12
date 2   apple    5
date 3   apple    7
date 1   pear     8
date 2   pear     3
etc...
```

I am trying to figure out how to compare rows with the row below it as long as the values in column 2 are the same. I don't believe the first column is important in solving the problem, but it is there to make the right order for the rest of the data. The third column is what I need to be doing the comparison then checking for the difference as it goes down the table. I need to keep track as to how many times it goes up and down. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it have to be done in SQL? Can you use a sql cursor?

Comment: You should go with a cursor then: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables to track the previous row and do a comparison against it

```
select col2, is_greater, count(*) from (
    select *, if(@prevCol2 = col2,@prevCol3 > col3,null) is_greater, 
         @prevCol3 := col3, @prevCol2 := col2
    from mytable
    order by col2, col1
) t1 group by col2, is_greater
```

Comment: Not going to lie, I am kinda confused at what I am looking at for the results. I took out the is_greater since it was always Null, but I see the second column entries once per item, which is good and a number beside it, which I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: @user1843804 what do you get when you run the query `select *, if(@prevCol2 = col2,@prevCol3 > col3,null) is_greater, 
         @prevCol3 := col3, @prevCol2 := col2
    from mytable
    order by col2, col1`

Comment: It looks like a join with 6 different columns

Comment: @user1843804 if the query doesn't work for you, you should probably alter your question to include your required/desired output